# Why g++ compiler is not able to find unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am trying to compile a small C++ code which invloves unique_ptr as given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<int> p1(new int);
}
```

when I tried to compile the code using g++, it is throwing up 'unique_ptr' was not declared in this scope. I was trying to compile on Linux box. even I tried with '-std=c++11' option. It was saying 'unrecognized command line option -std=c++11'. Can any one please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: You *say* you tried `-std=c++11`, but the error message you quote says you used `-std=C++11`. As you know, command-line options tend to be case-sensitive. That's why you're always advised to copy and paste rather than re-type what you think you have.

Comment: what's the version of the gcc you are using? Try from command prompt `$g++ --version` and report back.

Comment: It was saying g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7.3)

Comment: GCC 4.4.7 doesn't support C++11 dude.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: @40two is correct. I just remembered I had to figure out how to install GCC 4.7+ to use C++11 on a CentOS box a while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [GCC 4.4 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html), unique_ptr was not in GCC's standard C++ library before **4.4**.

So you might want to check your GCC version first, using `g++ --version` like @40two said.

Comment: g++ version : 4.4.7.3

Comment: You can try using `std=c++0x` instead of `std=c++11`, since 4.4.7 doesn't support C++11.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include it, it comes out of the [`<memory>` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
#include <memory>
```

Comment: Also `-std=c++11` could help afterwards.

Comment: Sorry. I included <memory> header file and tried with -std=C++11 but of no use

Comment: Hopefully you included <memory>, not <momory>

Comment: @CoryKramer Your `<momory>` goes to `<collage>`?